# How can I get in PHP the value out of an object attribute with the path stored in a variable?

Tags: php, object

For example, I have the following:
`$ValuePath = "object->data->user_nicename";`

And I need to print not the value of the $ValuePath but the value of the `$variable->data->user_nicename` that is part of a larger call .. as I have the following situation:

`echo $objects->$ValuePath->details;`

and is not working .. I'm getting the error Class cannot be converted to string or something when I try it like that.

Comment: What about some code?

Comment: You already have it up .. :          $ValuePath = "object->data->user_nicename";    echo $objects->$ValuePath->details;   as I'm trying to show the value stored in $objects->object->data->user_nicename->details

Comment: You're new here yound padawan... Show us some real code from what you are doing, then you may have some answers.

Comment: what about using `print_r()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP pseudo-code:

```
function get_by_path($object, $path)
{
    $o = $object;
    $parts = explode('->', $path);
    // if you want to  remove the first dummy object-> reference
    array_shift($parts);
    $l = count($parts);
    while ($l)
    {
        $p = array_shift($parts); $l--;
        if ( isset($o->{$p}) ) $o = $o->{$p};
        else {$o = null; break;}
    }
    return $o;
}
```

Use like this:

```
$value = get_by_path($obj, "object->data->user_nicename"); 
// $value = $obj->data->user_nicename;
```

Check also [PHP ArrayAccess Interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) which enables to access objects as arrays dynamicaly

Answer (score 0):

NO you cannot do that.

From your declaration `$ValuePath` is a variable which holds a plain string ('object->data->user_nicename') this string is not an object.
Where as, 
`$objects->object->data->user_nicename->details` is a object.

so `$objects->object->data->user_nicename->details` is not same as `$objects->$ValuePath->details`